# Perl foreach loop over one matrix row

Tags: perl, matrix, multidimensional-array, foreach

I want to loop over my row 1 in my matrix. Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @matrix;

$matrix[0][0] = 'zero-zero';
$matrix[1][1] = 'one-one';
$matrix[1][2] = 'one-two';

foreach my $line (@matrix[1]) {
        print "$line\n";
}
```

And I expect to get 'one-one' and 'one-two' here. But I get array reference as I understand. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to dereference `$matrix[1]` which is a reference to an array `[undef, "one-one", "one-two"]`

```
foreach my $line (@{ $matrix[1] }) {
    print "$line\n";
}
```